# Confusing statement about tension

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, free-body-diagram, string

[image]

Website writes

> The system is the tightrope walker, and the only external forces acting on him are his weight $W$ and the two tensions $T_L$ (left tension) and $T_R$ (right tension), as illustrated

To be precise isn't TL and TR acting on the rope rather than the man?

To calculate the tension we should apply newtons law on the rope element at the feet of the the man?

Website:

[https://pressbooks.bccampus.ca/physics0312chooge/chapter/4-5-normal-tension-and-other-examples-of-forces/#:~:text=Note%20that%20the%20vertical%20tension,the%20tension%20in%20the%20wire](https://pressbooks.bccampus.ca/physics0312chooge/chapter/4-5-normal-tension-and-other-examples-of-forces/#:%7E:text=Note%20that%20the%20vertical%20tension,the%20tension%20in%20the%20wire).

Comment: It may not be a _precise_ way to phrase this, but it is a _useful_ way. If you are not concerned about the shape of the wire or the walker's foot, and just consider forces balancing in a point then you will have to sum the three forces indicated (never mind the quibble about tension vs force) to find the proper balance. One of the skills of a physicist is to know how much rigor is enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"To calculate the tension we should apply newtons law on the rope element at the feet of the the man?"

You *can* do it this way. Two remarks...

• It would be better to call $\mathbf{T_A}$ and $\mathbf{T_B}$ 'tension forces' rather than 'tensions'.

• The justification for the downward force on the element of rope being equal to $\mathbf W$ is as follows... This downward force is the Newton's third law partner force to the upward push of the rope element on the man. This upward force is equal and opposite to the pull of the Earth, $\mathbf W$, on the man, because the man is in equilibrium and therefore has no resultant force on him.

Alternatively you can simply regard the element of rope and the man as one composite body with the forces $\mathbf{T_A}$, $\mathbf{T_B}$ and $\mathbf W$ acting on it !

[In both treatments we are neglecting the pull of the Earth on the element of rope, but that could easily be included.]

Comment: Thank you. But shouldn't we be careful to distinguish that the tension acts $on$the rope only. The vertical components also act $on$ the rope beneath the feet only. The rope applies a force on the man which is equal to the vertical components of the tension

Comment: But note my penultimate paragraph: "Alternatively you can regard the element of rope and the man as one composite body with the forces $\mathbf{T_A}$, $\mathbf{T_B}$ and $\mathbf W$ acting on it !" The preceding part of the answer treated the man and the element of rope as separate bodies, which I thought to be your approach. [Note that even if we use this approach we consider the feet of the man and the rest of the man as one body; we lump all the parts of him together as one composite body!

Answer (score 4):

This a problem which does not fully represent a real-life situation and contact between the man and the rope occurs at a **point**.

The only force that that can be exerted on the man by the rope is the net vertical component of the tension forces at the **point** of contact between shoe and rope.

All that being said the focus should be a section of rope which is at the **point** of contact with the shoe and is subjected to a downward vertical force due to the man and tension forces due the rest of the rope.

Comment: Thank you. But shouldn't we be careful to distinguish that the tension acts $on$the rope only. The vertical components also act $on$ the rope beneath the feet only. The rope applies a force on the man which is equal to the vertical components of the tension

Answer (score 3):

The weight of man is pulling him down towards the planet.

The tension forces $T_R$, $T_L$ are exerting the reaction force against the man's weight on him.

Thus,

$N = W = T_L \sin (5°) + T_R \sin (5°)$;

where,

$N$ represents the normal reaction force against $W$.

Answer (score 2):

Tension forces act *internal* to the rope. The external forces acting *on* the rope are the man, the reaction forces of the walls, and gravity (which can be ignored if the rope is considered massless). The external forces acting on the man are gravity and the vertical component of the tension force of the rope at the point where the rope contacts the man.

The tension forces internal to the rope are somewhat analogous to the compression forces that exist internal to the man. Both are the result of the external forces acting on each.

Hope this helps.

Comment: The vertical components also act on the rope element beneath the feet of man

Comment: @Kashmiri once again, that would be  an internal force in the rope.